# CSS border around img has gaps one screen and not on another

Tags: html, css

Here is a simple code I'm testing

```css
div {
  background-color: white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  max-width: 200px;
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="https://www.thedesignwork.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/Random-Pictures-of-Conceptual-and-Creative-Ideas-02.jpg">
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xhsngt3q/

On one monitor I get this

[image]

On the other one there's a white pixel border on the right and bottom

[image]

Any tips on how to remove that?

Comment: It's almost always zoom level when this happens.  Check your screen is set to actual size in browser and/or display settings to 100%.

Comment: @AuthenticScience I just checked that zoom lvl is 100% on both screens, but also the issue seems to happen in Chrome, with Firefox it looks fine in both monitors

Comment: You zoom level in the browser also 100% (CTRL-0, or CMD-0) in chrome?

Comment: @user1657533, Yes Authentic is right i also try in my monitor if i set zoom lvl 100% it's perfect, but if i zoom 110% i show right and bottom border.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is caused because of the number of pixels of the image.

I would suggest to add a black background to your image like the following CSS code:

```css
div {
  background-color: white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  max-width: 200px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  
  /*My change*/
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="https://www.thedesignwork.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/Random-Pictures-of-Conceptual-and-Creative-Ideas-02.jpg">
</div>
```

Hope this could be useful. Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with max-width:199px or max-width:202px

```css
div {
  background-color: white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
/*My change*/
  max-width: 199px;
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="https://www.thedesignwork.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/Random-Pictures-of-Conceptual-and-Creative-Ideas-02.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add box-shadow 0 0 0 1px; instead of the solid border. It is just a work around but sometimes good enough.

Answer (score -1):

```css
div {
  background-color: white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  max-width: 200px;
  border: 4px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="https://www.thedesignwork.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/Random-Pictures-of-Conceptual-and-Creative-Ideas-02.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Hey try this , I have changed 5 px to 4 px . this is working with all type of screen.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. You can try by zooming in and out.